# How to register a uniquePageview and how to use custom dimensions google analytics

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-reporting-api

I am working with custom dimensions to track my website.
I have a content based website. I want to track from which publisher my tracking is coming so I have developed something which uses parameters in my url for eg.
www.xyz.com?code=UNIQUECODE

this unique code Tells me which publishers link redirected to my page.
I run this UNIQUECODE through my database and send the id of the publisher associated with it using tag manager to my custom dimension i.e. PUBLISHER.

now I dont want to register another pageview for that particular publisher if the user refreshes or after a session ends.

what should be the scope of my custom dimension which persists the ID and not record another uniquePageview even if session ends.

Comment: Check the [Custom dimensions & metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#scope) as it mentions the 4 different kinds of scopes in the custom dimension.

Comment: Yeah I read but I am confused which scope to use.
can you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your aim correctly I don't think any of the available scopes will provide exactly what you are after. Essentially the scope options process the **last** value in the session but you want to process the first value in the session.

I think you would have to use hit-level scope because that is the only way to ensure the first value persists in reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why not just use UTMs but if you like it you way i recommend you to use a custom dimension at session level and use a trigger a little more specific that just checking for the 'code' parameter.

Build a custom JS that saves in the browser sessionStorage a flag that indicates if that person came with a 'code' in this session. This way the tag will fire only the first time a user enter the site with a 'code'. All the pageviews the user navigate after even if the 'code' parameter appear there will be a variable 'X' on the sessionStorage that avoids the tag to fire.

Finally, i strongly suggest you to avoid using debug mode to test this since it tends to break a lot with JS. Create a environment for Stage (Yes, tag manager has environments) and use the preview without debug.

If you need more info just ask. Good Luck.

Comment: I made a custom dimension which had a hit level scope which is sent with every pageview. As suggested by @Ben Hit scopes process the first value in the session and thus it helps me to keep scores.